# WOW64: get x64 %CommonProgramFiles% from 32 bit process

Tags: c++, winapi, wow64

Queries I tried: `ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%COMMONPROGRAMFILES%")`, `GetSpecialPath(CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES_COMMON)`.

All resolve to (typically) `c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files` from my 32-bit app. I need to check a file version installed (typically) under `c:\\Program Files\\Common Files` of a 64-bit application.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On 64-bit operating systems, the ProgramW6432 environment variable points to c:\program files.  The full list for a 32-bit app on an English version of Windows:

- ProgramFiles => c:\program files (x86)
- ProgramFiles(x86) => c:\program files (x86)
- ProgramW6432 => c:\program files
- CommonProgramFiles => c:\program files (x86)\common files
- CommonProgramFiles(x86) => c:\program files (x86)\common files
- CommonProgramW6432 => c:\program files\common files

Just a reminder: that folder should not contain anything of interest to a 32-bit program.  Technically.  Beware of the file system redirector, it will redirect file requests from c:\program files to c:\program files (x86).  You'd have to use Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection() if you'd actually wanted to access files in that directory.

Comment: I am just checking that a required (64 bit) application is already installed.

Comment: I know this is an old answer - but do you recall if your source for this information was https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/wow64-implementation-details#environment-variables (at whatever url/microsoft.com subdomain existed then.)

Answer (score 5):

%CommonProgramW6432%

Comment: Thanks! Somehow I missed that in the list of env variables.

Answer (score -1):

```
static string ProgramFilesx86()
        {
            if (8 == IntPtr.Size
                || (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432"))))
            {
                return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles(x86)");
            }

            return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles");
        }
```

Is this what you're needing?

Comment: That sure does not look like C++. Maybe C++/CLI but I'd bet C# given a guess.

Comment: I could have swore I saw C# on the tags. Sorry.